# how to access shared preferences and database on alarm receiver activity in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager

I want to access shared preferences on alarm receiver activity and database also.Is it possible to interact with DB on alarm receiver activity?
please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access shared preferences on alarm receiver activity and database also. Below is the sample code

```
public class AlarmSet extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    DBAdapter db;
  Context ct;
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        ct=context;

              db= new DBAdapter(ct);
              db.open();
                //do your stuff here
           }


}
```

Comment: i want to get details from DB by using web services. is it possible on alarm receiver activity?